# compare elements of a list from text file to CSV file, if element exist, print entire row from CSV file to a 3rd file

Tags: python, csv

I have a large CSV file looks like

**File1.csv**

```
id, First, Last, Address
aa, John, Doe, blah
bb, Bob, Smith, blahblah
cc, Alice, Johnson, blahblah
..
```

and 2nd file that's .txt file

**File2.txt**

```
id 
aa
cc
..
```

I want to output a file that contains all rows from first file that matches 2nd file

**Output.txt or csv**

```
id, First, Last, Address
aa, John, Doe, blah
cc, Alice, Johnson, blahblah
..
```

I browsed all day for answer but I can't find it. Im new to python and don't know what im doing

Answer (score 0):

Use Pandas to import both File1 and File2 as dataframes, with the 'id' column as the index. Then perform an inner merge:

```
import pandas as pd

file1_df = pd.read_csv('File1.csv', index_col=0)
file2_df = pd.read_csv('File2.txt', index_col=0)
merged_df = pd.concat([file1_df, file2_df], axis=1, join='inner')
merged_df.to_csv('Output.csv')
```

Comment: Might be unrelated but I have been trying this out but i kept getting the same "file does not exist error" :/ Both the python file and csv/txt files are in the same directory somewhere in local C drive. I tried tweaking with ' and " in file path as well as / and // and \ variants to specify file path but nothing worked...suggestions?

Comment: Hard to say but make sure that you're supplying the full and correct path to each file - `'C:/Some_Folder/File1.csv'`. If you're using backslashes, make sure to put `r` before your string so that it's interpreted as a raw string - `r'C:\Some_Folder\File1.csv'`.

Comment: I did what you suggested and now im getting "ValueError: shape of passed values is (15,26), indices imply (15,14)". Im using Python v3.6 and pandas 0.20.3

Comment: That probably means that you have rows with duplicate id's in `File1.csv`.